# Why RLWE is lighter than LWE and why we can pick $a_i$ as a permutation of $a_1$ in RLWE but not LWE?

Tags: hardness-assumptions, lwe, ring-lwe

In LWE, we have

$$<a_1,s> + e + \mu_1\in \mathbb{Z}_q$$

for a secret key $s\in \{0,1\}^n$ and $a_1\in \mathbb{Z}_q^n$

This is an encryption of a number $\mu_1$. If we want to encrypt $n$ different $\mu_i$, we need $n$ different $a_i$. With $n$ values $a_{11}, ..., a_{1n}$ we were able to encrypt one single $\mu_1$.

For RLWE, we have

$$a*s +e + m \in \mathbb{Z}_q[X]^n$$

for $a\in \mathbb{Z}_q[X]^n, e\in \mathbb{Z}_q[X]^n, m \in \mathbb{Z}_q[X]^n$, and $*$ is the polynomial multiplication modulo $x^n+1$. This is an encryption of a polynomial $m$ and thus the encryption of $n$ numbers $m_1,...,m_n$. With $n$ values $a_1, ..., a_n$ we were able to encrypt $n$ numbers.

I think this is what this answer meant to explain: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/47602. For encrypting $n$ values in LWE, we need a key size multiple of $n^2$ because of the $a$'s. For RLWE, we need just $n$. However, still for RLWE, on page 5 of the [PDF he linked](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/%7Eregev/papers/lwesurvey.pdf), he says that if we want to encrypt $n$ vectors, we can simply pick the $a_1\in \mathbb{Z}_q[X]^n$ and the others $a_i$ as functions of $a_1$ like this: $$\vec{a_i} = (a_i, ..., a_n, -a_1, ..., -a_{i-1}).$$ First of all, why this can be done for RLWE but not LWE? For LWE, we have a kind of system of linear equations:

$$a_{i1}s_1 + a_{i2}s_2 + ... + a_{in}s_n + e_i = bi \mbox{ mod q}$$

that is supposed to be hard to solve. If we make it such that $a_{i}$ is a permutation of $a_1$ then I think the problem is not hard anymore. Am I right? But why it is still hard on RLWE? Is it just because on RLWE we don't have a system of equations? We have

$$a_i*s +e_i + m_i = b_i \mbox{ mod $x^n$ + 1}$$

maybe $a_i$ being a permutation of $a_1$ here still leaves the problem hard, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

First, Regev is describing that RLWE can be viewed as a certain "structured" instance of LWE.
This is because

1. you can describe polynomials in terms of vectors in $\mathbb{Z}_q^n$,
2. you can describe *addition* of polynomials in terms of *addition* of vectors in $\mathbb{Z}_q^n$, and
3. you can describe *multiplication* of polynomials $\bmod (x^n+1)$ in terms of "funny scalar products" of vectors in $\mathbb{Z}_q^n$.

The last step is the only really non-trivial one.
I won't derive it all here, but one can show that the $i$th coefficient of the polynomial product $a(x)b(x)\bmod (q, x^n+1)$ is of the form $\langle \vec b, \mathsf{negacyclic}^{\circ i}(\vec a)\rangle$, where $\mathsf{negacyclic}^{\circ i}(\vec a)$ is the $i$-fold application of the operation that circularly shifts $\vec a$ (to the left or right, I always forget), and multiplies coefficients by $-1$ when they "wrap around".
Concretely, it is the $i$-fold iteration of the operation

$$(a_0,\dots,a_{n-1})\mapsto (-a_{n-1},a_0,\dots,a_{n-2}).$$

This is to say one can *exactly* describe a RLWE instance $(a(x), a(x)s(x) + e(x))$ by rewriting things in terms of integer vectors.
In particular, if you set $A$ to be the following matrix (where $[a,b,c]$ is a matrix with *columns* $a,b,c$)

$$A = [\mathsf{negacyclic}^{\circ 0}(\vec a),\mathsf{negacyclic}^{\circ 1}(\vec a),\dots, \mathsf{negacyclic}^{\circ (n-1)}(\vec a)],$$

then the aforementioned RLWE instance *exactly* corresponds to the LWE instance $(A, As + e)$.
As Regev mentions, this $A$ is no longer uniformly random over $\mathbb{Z}_q^{n\times n}$, as it is *entirely* specified by $O(n)$ elements.

> First of all, why this can be done for RLWE but not LWE?

To clarify, what is being done is *viewing RLWE as a structured form of LWE*.
One tradeoffs some assumptions of structure in the $A$ for some savings in efficiency.
As LWE is the "unstructured" version, one can't assume structure in an "unstructured" object.

> If we make it such that $\vec a_i$ is a permutation of $\vec a_1$ then I think the problem is not hard anymore.

As we are simply rewriting our RLWE instance in a different language, the "structured LWE" version is hard iff the RLWE version is hard.
So, RLWE can be viewed as saying that (for appropriate permutations) that the problem is **still** hard.

Note that not all permutations work.
This quickly becomes technical, but $\mathbb{Z}_q[x]/(x^n-1)$ was initially considered (by [Micciancio, for a Ring variant of the SIS problem](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Edaniele/papers/Cyclic.xml)).
This polynomial is not irreducible (it has a root at $x = 1$).
There is then a homomorphism (corresponding to evaluating polynomials at 1) that maps $a(x) \in\mathbb{Z}_q[x]/(x^n-1)\to \mathbb{Z}_q$, which leads to attacks.
Anyway, this is relevant because the multiplication on $\mathbb{Z}_q[x]/(x^n-1)$ corresponds to *cyclic* permutations of the $\vec a$ (rather than the *negacyclic* ones described above).

This all means that the set of all RLWE instances can be viewed as a subset of the set of all LWE instances.
From this perspective, RLWE can be no harder than LWE --- any algorithm breaking LWE equally breaks RLWE.
One may wonder how much easier the "RLWE subset" is --- there are some known lattice problems where things get *much* easier when you assume structure (I believe SIVP is the main example).
For the RLWE problem, there are additionally examples where *if parameterized wrong* things get easier, for example when you use $x^n-1$ an irreducible polynomial.
There are also some non-trivial quantum attacks on a close variant of the SVP problem for RLWE instances (I believe it is the short principle generator problem).

None of the above implies (for polynomials such as $x^{2^k}+1$, that are commonly used) better attacks against RLWE than exist for LWE though.
There are some authors (namely Bernstein) who believe the extra structure helps [1], but nothing has concretely been shown yet.

[1] He believes something more nuanced related to the size of Galois groups of the chosen polynomial $f(x)$ used in RLWE. The polynomial $x^{2^k}+1$ has a small Galois group, of size $O(\deg f)$. The size of the maximal galois group is $O((\deg f)!)$, much larger. Larger galois groups occur for random polynomials w.h.p., and are therefore "less structured". There are not known attacks utilizing the small Galois group of $x^{2^k}+1$.

Answer (score 0):

"we can simply pick $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}_q[X]^n$" => I think it should be just
$\mathbb{Z}_q^n$.

What you have to understand of this paragraph is the fact that encrypting

$\mu_0, \dots, \mu_{n-1}$ seen as a polynomial $\mu = \sum \mu_i X^i$ with RLWE and the polynomial $\sum a_i X^i$, is equivalent to encrypt each coordinate $\mu_j$ with LWE and the vector $\vec{a_j}=(a_{j}, a_{j+1}, \dots, a_{n-1}, -a_{1}, \dots, -a_{j-1})$.

Why is it true? Because if we look the coefficient of $X^j$ in
$a*s +e + \mu \in \mathbb{Z}_q[X]^n$, we obtain exactly

$<a_j,s> + e_j + \mu_j$ (with $e_j$ the coefficient of $X^j$ for the polynomial $e$).

About the hardness of the assumptions:
RLWE is a distinct (and easier) assumption than LWE.
Its security has been studied independently.
About the assumption you propose, but I only remark:

- You do not capture RLWE (because of the $-$).
- For some permutations, the problem becomes much easier:

For example, if $\sigma = (1,2)(3,4)\dots(n-1, n).$ (with your notation it's $i_j = i_j + 1$ if $i_j$ is odd, and $i_j -1$ if it's not).

Then we have $c_1= <a,s> + e_1 + \mu_1$, and
$c_2 = \sum^{n/2}_{j=1} (a_{2j}s_{2j-1} + a_{2j-1}s_{2j})  + e_2 + \mu_2.$

Then $c_1 + c_2 = 
\sum^{n/2}_{j=1} (a_{2j}s_{2j-1} + a_{2j-1}s_{2j}
+ a_{2j}s_{2j} + a_{2j-1}s_{2j-1}) + e_1+ e_2 + \mu_1+ \mu_2.$

$=\sum^{n/2}_{j=1} (a_{2j} + a_{2j-1})(s_{2j-1} + s_{2j-1}) + e_1+ e_2 + (\mu_1+ \mu_2).$

Then we have reduce the dimension of a factor $2$.

I would be tempted to generalise, and to say with a permutation of order $k$, you can reduce the dimension of a factor $k$ (then it's probably not secure).